# Long delay hiccups for logging stdout to file

Tags: c, performance

I have a C program that writes into 3 lines every 10ms into stdout. If I redirect the output to a file (using > ) there will be long delays (60ms) in the running of the program. The delays are periodic (say every 5 seconds).

If I just let it write to console or redirect to /dev/null, there is no problem.

I suspected that this is the stdout buffer problem, but using fflush(stdout) didn't solve the problem.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Since it is for logging, can I use non-blocking file for this purpose?

Comment: linux is not a real-time operating system, delays are unavoidable, especially when writing to disk.

Comment: @user3386109 , Sure, but I want to avoid this delay of logging. I already masked CPU core from kernel and pinned my process to the core. My problem now is this IO

Comment: Then I would suggest using shared memory to transfer the output to a process running on a different core, and let that process write it to disk.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `fsync`. The following:

`fsync(fileno(stdout))`

Should help. Note that the Linux kernel will still buffer limit I/O according to its internal scheduler limits. Running as root and setting a very low `nice` value might make a difference, if you're not getting the frequency you want.

If it's still too slow, try using `fdatasync` instead. Every `fflush` and `fsync` causes the filesystem to update node metadata (filesize, access time, etc) as well as the actual data itself. If you know in blocks how much data you'll be writing, then you can try the following trick:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

        FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");

        char *line = "Test\n";
        char *fill = "\0";

        fwrite(fill, 1, 100*strlen(line), fp);
        fflush(fp);
        fsync(fileno(fp));

        rewind(fp);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

                fwrite(line, strlen(line), 1, fp);
                fflush(fp);
                fdatasync(fileno(fp));

        }

}
```

The first fwrite call writes 5*100 zeros to the file in one chunk, and fsyncs so that it's written to disk and the node information is updated. Now we can write up to 500 bytes to the file without trashing filesystem metadata. `rewind(3)` returns the file pointer position to the beginning of the file so we can write over the data without changing the filesize of the node.

Timing that program gives the following:

```
$ time ./fdatasync
./fdatasync  0.00s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 0.913 total
```

So it ran fdatasync and sync'ed to disk 100 times in 0.913 seconds, which averages out to ~9ms per write & fdatasync call.

Comment: Still 9ms is too much for me. If my process waits 9ms every 10ms, that means that it almost has no time to do anything else.

Comment: @Masood_mj That's as good as you'll get as a general answer. Most disks aren't generally optimized for high amounts of small writes in a short space of time, and most filesystems aren't optimized for that either. You might have better luck calling fdatasync in another thread, but other than that - the solution is going to be better hardware + high performance filesystem + a kernel specifically tuned for high IOPS.

Answer (score 3):

> If I redirect the output to a file (using > ) there will be long
>   delays (60ms) in the running of the program.

That's because when `stdout` is a terminal device, it is usually (although not required) line-buffered, that is, the output buffer is flushed when a newline character is written, whereas in the case of regular files, output is fully buffered, meaning the buffers are flushed either when they are full or you close the file (or you explicitly call `fflush()`, of course).

`fflush(stdout)` may not be enough for you because that only flushes the standard I/O library buffers, but the kernel also buffers and delays writes to disk. You can call `fsync()` on the file descriptor to flush the modified buffer cache pages to disk after calling `fflush()`, as in `fsync(STDOUT_FILENO)`.

Be careful and don't call `fsync()` without calling `fflush()` before.

**UPDATE**: You can also try `sync()`, which, unlike `fsync()`, does not block waiting for the underlying writes to return. Or, as suggested in another answer, `fdatasync()` may be a good choice because it avoids the overhead of updating file times.

Comment: I tested fsync but it made the problem worse and now the delay happens 20 times per second. It seems fsync has long delay.

Comment: @Masood_mj see my edit - you'll have to use fdatasync and know the writes in advance if you want better performance. Real-time performant disk I/O is a challenge.

Comment: @Masood_mj Hum, perhaps because `fsync()` blocks until everything is written. Try `sync()` instead (see updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

it could be just that every 5seconds you are filling up your disk buffer and there is a spike in the latency due to flushing to actual disk.check with iostat

Comment: But if it is the problem, what could be the solution? Shall I make another process/thread and feed these output into it?